Flutter firestore: attempting to retrieve all documents of subcollection of the same collection
I'm new to flutter and firebase, but I'm attempting to retrieve images urls from an array field of all the documents in a subcollection and add them to a widget to display them.
This is my collection structure:

This is the code to access the Database
final UserPlantProfileProvider _userPlantProfileProvider =
    Provider.of<UserPlantProfileProvider>(context);
String? _userPlantProfileProviderImageID =
    Provider.of<UserPlantProfileProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .uPlantProfileImagesID;
String? _userPlantProfileProviderID =
    Provider.of<UserPlantProfileProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .uPlantProfileID;
final _userPlantProfileProviderImage =
    Provider.of<UserPlantProfileProvider>(context);
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _userPlantProfileStream = FirebaseFirestore
    .instance
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(AuthenticationRepository.instance.authUser?.uid)
    .collection('uPlant_Profile')
    .snapshots();


return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _userPlantProfileStream,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Something went wrong');
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          color: ColorStyles.primaryLColor,
        ),
      );
    }
    return GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisExtent: 210,
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 130,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        // getImage();
        final userPlantProfileData = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
        String pName = snapshot.data!.docs[index]['uPlantName']
            .toString()
            .capitalizeFirst!;
        String pSowingDate =
            snapshot.data!.docs[index]['uPlantSowingDate'].toString();
        _userPlantProfileProvider
            .uPlantProfileIDSetter(userPlantProfileData.id);

        var stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Users')
            .doc(AuthenticationRepository.instance.authUser?.uid)
            .collection('uPlant_Profile')
            .doc(_userPlantProfileProvider.uPlantProfileID)
            .collection('uPlantImages')
            .snapshots();
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: stream,
            builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot2) {
              if (snapshot2.hasError) {
                return Text('Something went wrong');
              }
              if (snapshot2.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: ColorStyles.primaryLColor,
                  ),
                );
              }
              if (snapshot2.data?.docs.length == 0) {
                return Center(
                    child: Container(child: Text('No Record Found!!!')));
              } else {
                return PageView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot2.data!.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    final imageData = snapshot2.data!.docs;
                    _userPlantProfileProviderImage
                        .uPlantProfileImagesIDSetter(
                            snapshot2.data!.docs[index].id);
                    _userPlantProfileProviderImage
                        .uPlantProfileImageUrlSetter(imageUrl.toString());
                    if (snapshot2.data!.docs.length <= 1) {
                      print(
                          "snapshot2.data!.docs.length ${snapshot2.data!.docs.length}");
                      imageUrl =
                          snapshot2.data!.docs[0]['uPlantImageUrl'][0];
                      print('This is less: ${imageUrl.toString()}');
                    } else {
                      print(
                          "snapshot2.data!.docs.length ${snapshot2.data!.docs.length}");
                      imageUrl = snapshot2.data!.docs[index]
                          ['uPlantImageUrl'][index];
                      print('This is Greater: ${imageUrl.toString()}');
                    }

                    // _userPlantProfileProviderImage.getUserPlantProfileImagesData(uPlant_Image: imageData['uPlantImageUrl'],uPlant_Image_TimeStamp: imageData["uPlantImageTimestamp"]).toString();
                    // print('_userPlantProfileProviderImage: ${_userPlantProfileProviderImage.uPlantProfileImagesID}');
                    // print('image URL: ${(imageUrl)}');
                    // print('imageData: ${imageData[0]['uPlantImageUrl'][index]}');
                    return GestureDetector(
                        child: RectangleImageTextVertical(
                      imageUrl: imageUrl.toString(),
                      title: pName,
                      subtitle: pSowingDate,
                      onTap: () async {
                        await Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return UserPlantProfileDetailScreen(
                            userPlantProfileImageDataLength:
                                snapshot2.data!.docs.length,
                            userPlantProfileData: userPlantProfileData,
                            userPlantProfileImageData: imageData,
                          );
                        }));
                      },
                    ));
                  },
                );
              }
            }));
      },
    );
  },
);

In this code the first stream is used to retrieve the document id for the first collection which is the plant profile subcollection, then using a setter in a provider I stored the id of the collection, and used it again in the second stream builder which is to retrieve the plant profile images. In this collection I want to retrieve all images  documents which consists of array of urls and timestamp.
The code works and I access all the fields I want except for the array of images, I only can retrieve one image index of each document.

Your current code returns a single GestureDetector for each document based on the first image URL in the uPlantImageUrl array:
imageUrl = snapshot2.data!.docs[0]['uPlantImageUrl'][0];

If you want to display multiple values from a document, you'll need to return a GestureDetector for each of those values. For example by returning a Column for each document, and then map its children to the array imageUrl = snapshot2.data!.docs[0]['uPlantImageUrl'], returning a GestureDetector for each value in the array.
final imageURLs = snapshot2.data!.docs[0]['uPlantImageUrl'];
if (imageURLs.length == 1) {
  final imageURL = imageURLs[0];
  // TODO: return a single GestureDetector for imageURL as you already do
}
else {
  return Column(
    children: imageURLs.map((imageURL) {
      // TODO: return  a GestureDetector for imageURL
    })
  );
}

